# How do I apply an externally generated signature to a PDF using itext7?

Tags: pdf, itext, itext7

I'm in the process of taking my first shot at applying a signature generated by a third party [AATL](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/approved-trust-list2.html) service to a PDF.

I feel like I'm calling everything *almost-correctly*, but somewhat unsurprisingly, when I view the signed document, I'm told that the signature is not valid.  There are many steps in this process where things can go wrong and as I am learning, this stumbling is expected.

Anyway, I'm looking for some guidance and to get some gaps in my knowledge filled. Before my code, I'll lay out what I think are the questions I need answered, you might see them in comments in the code as well:

1. Does it look like I'm using the right source for my digest? Namely `data`?
2. If the source is right, am I using the right technique to generate the digest? Namely, `DigestAlgorithms.digest(...)`?
3. The signature the third party service I call returns is base64 encoded.  Do I need to convert it from base64 to something else before returning the representation as a `ByteArray`?
4. I know I have to somehow use the certificates they make available to me, I'm just not sure where or how?
5. What is the signer `fieldName`?
6. How do I determine the right value for the `8192` I'm using for the `estimatedSize` parameter of `signer.signExternalContainer`?
7. How would I add CRL/OCSP information to the PDF?  Where does it typically come from when using a third party AATL signing service?

*Please feel free to point out any other suggestions or errors not in the list above!*

```kotlin
data class ThirdPartyCertificateResponse(val certs: List<String>)
data class ThirdPartySigningResponse(val sig: String, val nonce: String)

class ThirdPartySignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer {

    private lateinit var data: ByteArray

    override fun sign(data: InputStream): ByteArray {

        // note: I've omitted any validation of the nonce from this sample.
        val nonce = UUID.randomUUID()
        val digest = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, BouncyCastleDigest().getMessageDigest("sha256"))

        // note: The service I'm calling expects requests to look like this.
        //       I'm including this on the offchance that I'm accidentally 
        //       corrupting any of the data that I'm preparing for them.
        val bodyJson = JWSObject(
            JWSHeader(JWSAlgorithm.HS256),
            Payload(
                mapOf<String, Any>(
                    // note: `digestInfo` is an extension method that returns an `org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.DigestInfo` instance from a `ByteArray`
                    // note: Would love a tool that generates digests for me to check mine against! Hard to know if I'm doing the right thing here by basing it off of `data`??
                    "digestInfo" to digest.digestInfo().toBase64String(),
                    "nonce" to nonce.toString(),
                    "version" to 1,
                )
            )
        )

        bodyJson.sign(MACSigner("SHARED_SECRET"))

        val (_, _, signatureResult) = "https://thidpartyservice.notreal/api/v1/signatures"
            .httpPost()
            .body(bodyJson.serialize())
            .responseObject<ThirdPartySigningResponse>()

        val signatureText = when (signatureResult) {
            is Result.Failure -> throw signatureResult.getException()
            is Result.Success -> signatureResult.value.sig
        }

        return signatureText.decodeBase64()
            ?: throw Exception("Unable to decode response from third party service")
    }

    override fun modifySigningDictionary(dictionary: PdfDictionary) {

        val (_, _, certificateResult) = "https://thidpartyservice.notreal/api/v1/certs"
            .httpGet()
            .responseObject<ThirdPartyCertificateResponse>()

        val certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("x.509")

        // note: I have no idea what to do with these, but I've got them!
        val certificateChain = when (certificateResult) {
            is Result.Failure -> throw certificateResult.getException()
            is Result.Success -> certificateResult.value.certs.map {
                certificateFactory.generateCertificate(it.decodeBase64()?.inputStream())
            }
        }

        // note: What are these doing?
        dictionary.put(PdfName.Filter, PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite)
        dictionary.put(PdfName.SubFilter, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached)

        // note: I feel like I should be adding the certificate(s) to `dictionary` here...?
    }
}
```

The above class is instantiated and called from code as follows:

```kotlin
val stampingProperties = StampingProperties()
val signer = PdfSigner(thisPdfReader, thisSigned.outputStream(), stampingProperties)
// note: What's this?
signer.fieldName = null

signer.signatureAppearance
    .setPageRect(Rectangle(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f))
    .setPageNumber(1)

val container: IExternalSignatureContainer = ThirdPartySignatureContainer()

// note: I don't know how to determine a correct value for it, so I've left 8192 in here from examples I've seen.
signer.signExternalContainer(container, 8192)
```

[This is a sample of a PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BIS4-zAGg-x2XeVWnFQGWw_h8fE9zrKi/view?usp=sharing) that I'm currently generating.

Comment: Can you share an example pdf signed by your code for analysis? Usually it's easier to determine the code issue knowing how exactly the result fails validation.

Comment: @mkl - Added a link to a PDF for you to check out, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `class ThirdPartySignatureContainer` implements `IExternalSignatureContainer`; thus, its `sign` method is expected to return a *CMS signature container* to embed as is in the PDF. Inspecting [your example file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BIS4-zAGg-x2XeVWnFQGWw_h8fE9zrKi/view?usp=sharing), though, it becomes clear that your remote signature service - and so also your `sign` method - returns *naked signature bytes*.

Thus, you should instead implement `IExternalSignature` the `sign` method of which is expected to return naked signature bytes. To sign you would then use a `signer.signDetached` overload instead of `signer.signExternalContainer`.

This also would imply an answer to your question *how to add CRL/OCSP information to the PDF* - the `signDetached` overloads have `ICrlClient` and `IOcspClient` parameters, too, which can provide CRLs and OCSP responses to embed.

Comment: Amazing!  Alright, looks like that got things signed, so I wasn't too far off.  Do you have any references on where/how I might specify the CRL, OCSP and ITSA clients?  I saw examples providing `..., null, null, null, ...`.  Is that to say none, or "use defaults"?

Comment: `null` means none. For Java examples look at [i7js-signatures](https://github.com/itext/i7js-signatures/tree/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/signatures/chapter03) itext 7 samples on github, in particular `C3_09_SignWithTSA.java`, `C3_07_SignWithOCSP.java`, `C3_04_SignWithCRLOnline.java`, and `C3_05_SignWithCRLOffline.java`. They are ports of the iText 5 samples from the [Digital Signatures for PDF Documents](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/digital-signatures-pdf) white paper.

Comment: Gotcha, so more reading for me!  -- Any idea why this is failing validation?  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1As_eeCxSYpKtjrIF0o_o-rwMQfkfnQmG/view?usp=sharing -- It's telling me "Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed" and also "Signing time is from the clock on the signer's computer."

Comment: There is an algorithm mismatch. The SignerInfo in your signature container selects SHA256 and the encrypted DigestInfo contains the appropriate SHA256 hash value, ***but it claims it is a SHA512 hash value***. Maybe you have to change your call to the signing server in question to include your chosen hash algorithm, or maybe you have to switch to SHA512.

Comment: Once again -- amazing, thank you!  How were you able to determine this?

Comment: I have started writing a tool that digs up sich issues - https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/signature/PdfSignatureAnalyzer.java - one has to know how to read the outputs ;).